# alinhamento horizontal com css

Tags: css

Como faço para deixar o 'título' alinha com o ícone sem a necessidade de colocar o 'título' dentro de alguma div.

```css
.card-blue,
.card-red,
.card-green,
.card-grey,
.card-yellow {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 10px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 50px 0;
}

.card-grey {
  border: 1px solid #484848 !important;
}

.card-blue {
  border: 1px solid #0091FF !important;
}

.card-red {
  border: 1px solid #f65314 !important;
}

.card-green {
  border: 1px solid #34a853 !important;
}

.card-yellow {
  border: 1px solid #fbbc05 !important;
}

.card-red-head,
.card-blue-head,
.card-green-head,
.card-grey-head,
.card-yellow-head {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.card-grey-head {
  background: #484848;
}

.card-blue-head {
  background: #0091FF;
}

.card-red-head {
  background: #f65314;
}

.card-green-head {
  background: #34a853;
}

.card-yellow-head {
  background: #fbbc05;
}


/* Mobile */

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .card-blue,
  .card-red,
  .card-green,
  .card-grey,
  .card-yellow {
    width: 95%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="card-red">
  <div class="card-red-head">
    <i class="material-icons">delete</i> TÍTULO
  </div>
  <div class="container-body">
    texto
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você pode ao invés de setar um id, setar uma class
#div {
}

em vez disso usar 
.classe {
}

E no html

<label ide="minhaDiv" class="classe">

Comment: poderia criar uma resposta com o código alterado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria isso? Coloquei a tag `<a>` e o ícone e título dentro dela. E no css, adicionei a seguinte linha `.card-red-head i{ margin-top:-4px;float:left; }`. Que no caso formata o posicionamento do ícone em relação ao texto. Espero ter ajudado, qualquer dúvida comente ai!

```css
.card-blue,
.card-red,
.card-green,
.card-grey,
.card-yellow {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 10px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 50px 0;
}

.card-grey {
  border: 1px solid #484848 !important;
}

.card-blue {
  border: 1px solid #0091FF !important;
}

.card-red {
  border: 1px solid #f65314 !important;
}

.card-green {
  border: 1px solid #34a853 !important;
}

.card-yellow {
  border: 1px solid #fbbc05 !important;
}

.card-red-head,
.card-blue-head,
.card-green-head,
.card-grey-head,
.card-yellow-head {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.card-grey-head {
  background: #484848;
}

.card-blue-head {
  background: #0091FF;
}

.card-red-head {

  background: #f65314;
}
 .card-red-head i{ margin-top:-4px;float:left; }
.card-green-head {
  background: #34a853;
}

.card-yellow-head {
  background: #fbbc05;
}


/* Mobile */

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .card-blue,
  .card-red,
  .card-green,
  .card-grey,
  .card-yellow {
    width: 95%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="card-red">
  <div class="card-red-head">
    <a><i class="material-icons">delete</i>TÍTULO</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container-body">
    texto
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Complementando a resposta do nosso amigo LocalHost, eu faria assim:

```css
.box{
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #e67e22;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.box-header{
  background-color: #e67e22;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.box-header i, .box-header p{
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="box">
  <div class="box-header">
    <i class="material-icons">delete</i> 
    <p>Título</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-content">
    <p>texto</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

O segredo esta em deixar os elementos filhos de `box-header` com o `display: inline-block` após os filhos trabalhando em linha é só alinhar verticalmente com `vertical-align: middle` com essa técnica não precisamos trabalhar com `float` que originalmente foi criado para alinhar imagens em textos, e também evita precisar usar aqueles `clear: both`